# Issue while clone a git repository in source tree

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fzAm.png)

I know that similar questions have already been posted here. However, I think my scenario is a bit different. Here is what I have.

I downloaded and installed the latest official version of the SourceTree software. Also, I have a GitHub account with permissions to clone and push the repository. In order to manage a local copy, I need to clone the online version.

ERRORfatal: destination path 'D:\dev\repo\t1' already exists and is not an empty directory.

That's it, it resolved my issue.
I tried to re-install SourceTree but the error still exists. I asked the Administration of the GitHub repository for any other permissions but my account has all of them. I am able to push changes to the online repository using the Terminal console but I would like to use a UI (that SourceTree provides) to manage and compare changes in the code.

One think I did not try is to clone the repository using another GtHub account. However, I don't want to do that because I need to commit any changes to the repository on my behalf.

Does anybody know how can this error be fixed or worked around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. first of all go to clone as and put the repo's HTTPS link in the Source Path option and Browse it.
2. set the Destination Path in Sorucetree then you can clone it.